# Spark spark-sql-kafka - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/kafka/common/serialization/ByteArraySerializer

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I am experimenting with spark reading from a kafka topic through ["Structured Streaming + Kafka Integration Guide"](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html#deploying).

Spark version: 3.2.1
Scala version: 2.12.15

Following their guide on the spark-shell including the dependencies, I start my shell:

```
spark-shell --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.2.1
```

However, once I run something like the following in my shell:

```
val df = spark.readStream.format("kafka").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers","http://HOST:PORT").option("subscribe", "my-topic").load()
```

I get the following exception:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/kafka/common/serialization/ByteArraySerializer`

Any ideas how to overcome this issue?

My assumption was with using --packages, all dependencies should be loaded as well. But this does not seem to be the case. From the logs I assume that the package gets loaded successfully, including the kafka-clients dependency:

```
org.apache.spark#spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12 added as a dependency
resolving dependencies :: org.apache.spark#spark-submit-parent-3b04f646-471c-4cc8-88fb-7e32bc3226ed;1.0
confs: \[default\]
found org.apache.spark#spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12;3.2.1 in central
found org.apache.spark#spark-token-provider-kafka-0-10_2.12;3.2.1 in central
found org.apache.kafka#kafka-clients;2.8.0 in central
found org.lz4#lz4-java;1.7.1 in central
found org.xerial.snappy#snappy-java;1.1.8.4 in central
found org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.7.30 in central
found org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-client-runtime;3.3.1 in central
found org.spark-project.spark#unused;1.0.0 in central
found org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-client-api;3.3.1 in central
found org.apache.htrace#htrace-core4;4.1.0-incubating in central
found commons-logging#commons-logging;1.1.3 in central
found com.google.code.findbugs#jsr305;3.0.0 in central
found org.apache.commons#commons-pool2;2.6.2 in central
```

Answer (score 0):

The logs seem fine, but you can try to include `kafka-clients` dependency in `--packages` argument as well

Otherwise, I'd suggest creating an uber jar instead of downloading libraries every time you submit the app

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried adding the kafka-clients also, no solution, unfortunately.  I think it's weird that their official instructions do not seem to work. But I'll give the uber jar a try.

Comment: It somewhat works, since your logs clearly say `found org.apache.kafka#kafka-clients`, so maybe something is wrong with the actual Maven package that got downloaded